# Ошибка при создании базы данных(отношение не существует)

Tags: postgresql

ERROR: ОШИБКА: отношение "orders" не существует

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
mfr_id VARCHAR(255)PRIMARY KEY,
product_id INTEGER UNIQUE,
description VARCHAR(255),
price DECIMAL,
qty_on_hand  INTEGER
);
 
CREATE TABLE Customers(
cust_num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
company VARCHAR(255),
cust_rep INTEGER REFERENCES Orders(cust),
credit_limit DECIMAL
);
 
CREATE TABLE Orders(
order_num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
order_date DATE,
mfr VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES Products(mfr_id),
product INTEGER REFERENCES Products(product_id),
qty INTEGER,
amount DECIMAL,
cust INTEGER REFERENCES Customers(cust_rep),
rep INTEGER REFERENCES SalesReps(rep_office)
);
 
CREATE TABLE SalesReps(
empl_num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255),
age INTEGER,
rep_office INTEGER REFERENCES Orders(rep),
title VARCHAR(255),
hire_date DATE,
manager INTEGER REFERENCES Offices(mgr),
quota DECIMAL,
sales DECIMAL
);
 
CREATE TABLE Offices(
office INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
city VARCHAR(255),
region VARCHAR(255),
mgr INTEGER REFERENCES SalesReps(manager),
target DECIMAL,
sales DECIMAL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблица `Customers` ссылается на `Orders`, если конкретней, то тут создается внешний ключ `cust_rep INTEGER REFERENCES Orders(cust)`.

Так как у вас циклическая зависимость то нужно добавлять внешний ключ отдельной командой уже после того, как таблица, на которую ссылается ключ, уже создана:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_order_cust
   FOREIGN KEY (cust_rep) 
   REFERENCES Orders(cust)
   DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Обратите внимание, что из-за того, что у вас циклические зависимости, вам нужно эти ограничения сделать отложенными (DEFERRABLE) (то же касается и внешних ключей из таблицы `Orders`. Иначе (без отложенных ограничений) будет невозможно создать записи, так как при вставке, например, в `Orders` уже нужно будет, чтоб в `Customers` существовала запись и наоборот. Отложенные ограничения не проверяются во время вставки, а выполняются при фиксировании (комите) транзакции.

Comment: ERROR: ОШИБКА:  отношение "customers" не существует

Comment: если у меня другая база на эту ссилаеться и эта на нее, то есть какая-то двозвязаний связь